# Compatibility problem iAd Banner?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

Hi i am using iAd Banner in my test aap.It works fine  with 4.0 Sdk but when i went with SDK 3.0 or before ,it crashes without showing anything.I read that weaklink will help me regarding this problem but as per my thinking it crashes when it doesn't find the framework.I do not even know that how to use Weak-link.Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the Targets directory, right click , and choose “Get Info”. Click the Build tab, make sure “All Configurations” is selected, and navigate to Linking\Other Linker Flags. Double click on that entry, click the “+” button, and type “-weak_framework iAd”.

Comment: @Ghimire : i did this as you mention above but its still showing errors in iAd framework and ADBanner class

Comment: ok try
Expand the Targets directory, right click , and choose “Get Info”.in general you can see linked libraries select iAD.framework in in type select weak good luck

Comment: @Ghimire: Should i commented the "#import <iAd/iAd.h>",delegate and IBOutlet because its showing errors.I again did the same u mentioned above but its again showing the same error.

Comment: follow this tutorial man http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app good luck

Comment: @Ghimire: I have already read this tutorial.After doing the same it's showing the 17 errors in the project when i changed the Active Target.

Comment: i guess you have previous value in other linker flag , so when you change all setting to new value old value is gone ,so first find out what is the value previously set in other linker flag and add new weak link flag too good luck

Answer (score 0):

When allocating your ADBannerView, first check to see if the OS version supports it:

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"AdBannerView")) {
     //Allocate ADBannerView here
}
```

Then in the build settings of your target, add `-weak_framework iAd` to **Other Linker Flags** in the **Linking** section.

Edited as per Jonathans recommendation.

Comment: Woah. Ew. Don't do that. `-respondsToSelector:` is gonna trigger the load of the symbol too. Use `NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView")`.

Comment: Nothing happens using this condition because it's showing error in very above "#import <iAd/iAd.h>" please tell me how could i fix it?